# Getting error while Selecting MAX value from Count() in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I'm getting an error while applying `MAX` and `COUNT` in SQL Server, even though my code is correct. Please assist me where I'm going wrong

Display the id of the person who has packed maximum number of items from Sales.Invoices table

```
select 
    PackedByPersonID, count(PackedByPersonID) 
from 
    Sales.Invoices 
group by 
    PackedByPersonID 
having 
    count(PackedByPersonID) = (select max(max_count) 
                               from 
                                   (select PackedByPersonID, count(PackedByPersonID) max_count 
                                    from Sales.Invoices 
                                    group by PackedByPersonID))
```

While executing SQL is unable to identify max_count in the code.. as it was underlined by red and was showing "Invalid column name 'max_count'"

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
> Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: Your code is not correct.  If it were correct, you would not be getting an error.

Comment: give your table sub query an alias

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, to be clear, a *syntax error* definitely means the code is not correct.  Other errors may not be a fault of the current code being incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using window functions or `TOP` for this.  But your syntax error is because all subqueries in the `FROM` clause require an alias in SQL Server.  So:

```
select PackedByPersonID, count(PackedByPersonID)
from Sales.Invoices 
group by PackedByPersonID 
having count(PackedByPersonID) = (
           select MAX(max_count)
           from (select PackedByPersonID, count(PackedByPersonID) max_count
                 from Sales.Invoices 
                 group by PackedByPersonID
                ) i
------------------^ the table alias
          )
```

A simpler and more efficient way to write the query is:

```
select top (1) with ties PackedByPersonID, count(*)
from Sales.Invoices 
group by PackedByPersonID 
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: Nice, that's a hard one to find by eye.